# Simplify an integral formula

Tags: integration, derivatives

I stuck on a statement in the book [Mixed Boundary Value Problems - Dean G. Duffy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584885793). In page 107, he gives
$$
h(t) = \dfrac{2}{\pi} \dfrac{d}{dt}\left\lbrace \int_0^t \dfrac{\cos(x/2)}{\sqrt{\cos(x) - \cos(t)}} \left[\int_0^x f(\xi) d\xi \right]dx\right\rbrace
$$
then he claims
$$
h(t) = \frac{2}{\pi}\cot\left(\frac{t}{2}\right) \int_0^t \frac{\sin(x/2)f(x)}{\sqrt{\cos(x) - \cos(t)}}dx
$$
Here we assume $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

I don't understand how he simplified $h(t)$ from the first equation to the second equation. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: +1 for a good question, and a link to a good book. I would have thought you need to use differentiation under the integral sign. What worries me though is that when I substitute $x=t$ into the denominator, it's singular.